# Store data from online JSON into Amazon aws (rds or dynamo)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

I have some JSON data, I want to record this JSON into my Amazon DB. Is there anyway to do it? I researched some info but nothing helped.

Comment: What specifically have you tried?

Comment: Amazon offers a wide variety of Database solutions. Amongst the most common ones are Amazon RDS (relational databases) and DynamoDB (Amazon's hosted NoSQL database). I would recommend figuring out what you need to store in the database and how it's going to be used. After that you can make a decision as to which AWS service to use.

Comment: @RyanM I havent tried anything yet, i dont know how to make etl on amazon.

Comment: @NickPestov I already have the solution, Just dont know how to feed amazon from json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PostgreSQL on RDS you can take advantage JSON specific datatypes and functions.

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Thanks, It really helped me out.